# module 'ng' has no exported member 'ui' when using ui-router type definition for typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webstorm

I am trying to use this typescript definition file for `ui-router`:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.d.ts

Here is the code at the top of the definition file:

```
// Type definitions for Angular JS 1.1.5+ (ui.router module)
// Project: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
// Definitions by: Michel Salib <https://github.com/michelsalib>
// Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

/// <reference path="../angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

declare module ng.ui {

    interface IState {
    ...
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
module MyModule
{
    export class MyStateConfig
    {
        constructor(
            //                     -> error on the word ng.ui on next line
            private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, 
            private $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider
            ...)
        {
            this.$stateProvider.state(...
```

This was working in Visual Studio but now with WebStorm I get a message saying "

> module 'ng' has no exported member 'ui'

Can someone give me advice on this. Is this something to do with a different module system with WebStorm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding a reference comment in your module source file? Something like...

```
/// <reference path="path/to/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.d.ts" />
```

Visual Studio doesn't require this because its msbuild tasks automatically tell the compiler to reference any definition that are included in the project. I'm guessing WebStorm doesn't use msbuild project files.

Comment: Maybe a bit off topic but do you know how I can see where the msbuild does the referencing?

Comment: Open the project file with a text editor (it's an xml file) or just Edit project file from context menu of the project in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the [@types/angular-ui-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular-ui-bootstrap) npm package is installed.

   `npm install @types/angular-ui-bootstrap`
2. Check your **tsConfig.json** file, in `compilerOptions`, look for a `types` array.  Try removing `types` or replacing with `typeRoots`.  Something like this:

   `"compilerOptions": {
       "target": "ES5",
       "sourceMap": true,
       ....
       ....
       "typeRoots": [
         "node_modules/@types"
       ]
     },`

Comment: Thanks  installing the types did it for me.